# Can't load video in second screen

Tags: vb.net

I planing to have a video in 2nd form at second screen.
I used below commands to create video in my second screen.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim screen As Screen
    'Show the form on second screen
    screen = screen.AllScreens(0)
    Form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    Form2.Location = screen.Bounds.Location + New Point(100, 100)
    Form2.Show()
```

normally these windows are opening fine with 2 screens.
if I put some video in form2, then both forms are opening in same screen.

Comment: Wouldn't `AllScreens(0)` be the _first_ screen?

Comment: In my PC  AllScreens(0) is the second screen.